# Is it possible to pair a keyboard without entering a passcode?

Tags: windows, windows-10, bluetooth

I have a Bluetooth media remote with pause/play, skip forward/skip backwards, vol up/down buttons. It has no other buttons. And Microsoft Bluetooth stack requires a passcode, which I physically cannot enter. I've tried Bluesoleil and Toshiba stacks, they require passcode as well. I have not found a way to skip the pass with either of these 3 stacks. The only one I can't try is Broadcom, I don't have their USB bluetooth dongle and their stack only works with their chipsets, it seems. Does Widcomm allow connecting a BT keyboard without entering a passkey?

Is there any way to connect my BT remote on Windows?

P. S. The same device pairs with Android phone no problem since Android does not require a passcode.

[image]

Comment: oooh. That's bad design. It might be handy to say what the media remote actually is - USB makes me assume something wired, and bluetooth not.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: this is the device, hopefully it's self-explanatory http://img.banggood.com/images/oaupload/banggood/images/03/B2/3b7a9c82-c6a7-0c88-138e-ac4bd66d9153.jpg

Comment: errrrr. Nope. Wierdly a store listing might be. Or a manual.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: alright, how about this? http://www.banggood.com/BT-005-12M-Bluetooth-Media-Button-Support-IOS-Bluetooth-3_0-Android-OS-4_0-p-1017379.html

Comment: hmm. So, in theory it shouldn't work. But... https://www.wayneandlayne.com/blog/2010/06/14/bluetooth-keyboard-pairing-without-code-entry/ says it might. Try it, and report back ;)

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: Well, it only shouldn't work because of an artificial limitation of the Windows Bluetooth stack. I've seen that article but paid no attention because it's for Linux. Let me check it out.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: if you're referring to the Windows part of that article - it's for Windows 7 which did have the option for key-less pairing. Windows 8 and 10 do not. Windows 7 can't even be installed on the PC where I need to use this remote.

Comment: [Bluesoleil](http://www.bluesoleil.com/) (shareware, $27.99) might be be able to do it, although unfortunately it costs more than this remote....

Comment: @harrymc: as I said in the question, I have tried Bluesoleil and it also requires a passkey. I don't care what it costs, I need it to work. I'm going to make an Arduino-based Bluetooth-to-USB bridge, but I don't feel I have exhausted the software options since this is clearly an artificial obstacle.

Comment: If you don't care what it costs, buy a better remote with a real keyboard. Looking on amazon.com, they don't cost more than your actual one.

Comment: In consideration of the lives of your fellow drivers, maybe you should consider using some other gadget to hold your music than your laptop? There are many of these.

Comment: @harrymc: it's called "Car PC", not a laptop.

Comment: Nevertheless, there are gadgets specialized in car music with steering-wheel attachment that don't run Windows 10 and are not subject to Microsoft's caprices (or inaptness?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pairing without pin is possible in windows, but not supported by the default GUI. Take a look at `ConfirmOnly` option on this [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/mt608808):

> ConfirmOnly
>
> The application must confirm they wish to perform the pairing action. You can present an optional confirmation dialog to the user. With a value of ConfirmOnly, Accept the pairing if you want it to complete.

Microsoft provides [code examples](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/DeviceEnumerationAndPairing) of applications with different pairing GUIs, which could be a starting point for someone with Visual Studio and some free time.

Comment: Ii works! I didn't even get to write any code: the sample you gave a link to already does everything. Moreover, once the device was paired with security measures off, I can use the standard Bluetooth control panel. I can even unpair it and pair again with no passkey still.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe Hey, I'm glad it helped, and thanks for reporting back so quickly.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe, When in Device Enumeration and Pairing C# Sample I choose Custom Device Pairing > Bluetooth and only tick "ConfirmOnly" it fails with Pairing result = RequiredHandlerNotRegister, what exactly did you select in the UI? Which protection level and which checkboxes?

Comment: @axk: first of all, I didn't use the C# sample, I used the UWP C++ sample. Perhaps, they're not 100% identical application. I don't recall having to fiddle at all, it just worked right away in a single slick.

Answer (score 3):

As far as anyone can tell.... no you can't.  There's no option for keyless pairing in Windows 10 and this feels like an OS level decision.

It might be a bug, it might be intentional, but unless someone can prove otherwise, you cannot do it in Windows 10.

Comment: The requirement is by design. When connecting, one has to enter a code to be able to encrypt the transmission. If you were communicating via bluetooth unencrypted, anyone with a bluetooth receiver could pick up everything you type.

Comment: @user186658: I can clearly see it's by design.

Comment: It cannot be disabled without writing your own driver:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/2d787546-2dea-4d8c-89b0-8ac9b78b8b5a/disabling-bluetooth-pairing-passcodes?forum=w8itprohardware

I realize the post is in regard to Windows 8, but it applies across all versions.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible in Windows 7. Just go to the properties of connecting device, then tick on use HID etc. That Bluetooth properties can no longer be found in Windows 10.

Comment: I know it's possible in Windows 7. My question is specifically about Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is a simple way to pair a Bluetooth mouse in Windows 10. You just have to go into the old Control Panel to Add a Device. Don't use the Win10 Settings interface. In the old CC interface, when asked for a code, ignore it and click NEXT. On my Dell laptop, it installed the driver. I rebooted it and the HP N558 mouse works without fuss. I had also done that with the MS Surface Pro 4.

Comment: What does this do and how will it help?

Answer (score 0):

Seconding @pzwong with this.

If you go to the classic Control Panel, and add a bluetooth device that way, it may ask for a PIN, but instead of the OK/Confirm button being deactivated unless a PIN is entered, will allow you to continue adding the device while not requiring PIN entry to proceed.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it did not work that way,but I can no longer try that particular BT device. I still have the device but it's not detected by my new mini PC. So I just bought another BT remote that looks almost the same, but it's not 100% identical and given four years have passed, I'm sure its BT chip has also been updated. And Windows has been updated many times, too. Bottom line: this new device does not require a pin when pairing using the standard Windows 2004 UI.